# How can I populate a custom field other than the available ones in Process builder to schedule an action?

Tags: process-builder, scheduled-action

I have a requirement where an email has to be fired after 3 days the Applicant's Go_Live_Status__c is set. But the issue is I couldn't see that field in the "Select Date Field" in the scheduled action section in Process Builder. I can see other Date fields but I cannot use those to fulfill this requirement.
I want to know is there any way to add a field?
If not please suggest me an alternative method to achieve this.
Thanks!

Comment: Is `Go_Live_Status__c` a formula field?  Process Builder can't use formula fields to trigger scheduled actions.

Comment: did you check fls for Go_Live_Status__c?

Answer (score 0):

you can set the scheduled action to run 3 days from "now" (the day where Go_Live_Status__c is set)

[image]

Comment: The OP is saying that he can't see the field at all in the date selector.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your thoughts and inputs guys. It is a Date field but on other the other object. The object on which I'm building the PB have a Lookup relation with that object and I though PB can read those related fields too. No I have to build a new PB on that object as I cannot use formula field.
Thanks again.